# mobile-chrome-app GCM not receiving messages

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Im trying to get my chrome-cordova app to receive messages by the chrome.gcm api but its not working,

The console outputs that the device has registered but when i try to send a message to that ID i get nothing,

Here is my background.js file:

```js
/**
 * Listens for the app launching then creates the window.
 * Ignores the provided window size.
 *
 * @see http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/app.window.html
 */
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    width: 244,
    height: 380,
  });
});

var GCM_SENDERID = '224595526060';
var GCM_SENDER = GCM_SENDERID + '@gcm.googleapis.com';

(function main() {
  var errorLogger = function() {
    console.error.apply(console, arguments);
  };
  chrome.gcm.onSendError.addListener(errorLogger);
  chrome.gcm.onMessagesDeleted.addListener(errorLogger);

  chrome.gcm.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    console.info('got GCM message', msg);
   
  });

  chrome.gcm.register([GCM_SENDERID], function(regid) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError || regid === -1) {
      console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
      return;
    }
    console.info('GCM connect success, reg', regid);
    
  });
}());
```